# Cross Domain Web API: Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors Not Working

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cross-domain, nuget-package

As Cross Domain call to Web API project not working from ASP.NET Web Forms client in IE (Working in other browsers). I guess I need to install following Nugget pakage.

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors

But when I try to install it I got following error.

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.1.2'. You are trying to install 
this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any as
sembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors -pre -project WebAPI
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I am trying to install in:
Visual Studio 2010 which targets .NET 4.0.

Does this package is not supported in .NET 4.0 ?

Best Regards
Hardeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET `4.5` is a minimal requirement for 5.0 version and above of Web API.

Comment: Thanks Kiran. Yes I found this. Cross domain API work on my home PC which has VS 2012 installed. In office is VS2010 and we need to upgrade Visual Studio for this or use WCF (which I hate becasue of configuratio issues all the time)